# ArrayList updated inserting one row but Jtable still not refresh

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, oracle11g, jtable

I've to create a java swing app that allows the user to menage some Oracle tables.

I've implemented the JTable in this way:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
        .
        .
        .

  public List <List <String> > result = null;     
        .
        .
        .
  public void createTable(ResultSet r) throws SQLException {
    rs = r;
    numcols = getColumnCount();
    result = new ArrayList();
    while (rs.next()) {
      List <String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols);
      for (int i=1; i<= numcols; i++)
          row.add(rs.getString(i).replace("00:00:00.0", "")); //just managing stuffs .. nothing important. Don't care of this replace.
      result.add(row);
     }
     fireTableStructureChanged();
   }

  public void addRow(){ 
    List <String> row = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=getColumnCount();i++)
        row.add("");
    result.add(row);
    fireTableStructureChanged();
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return result.get(row).get(col);
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
  if (rs == null) {
     return 0;
  }
  try {
     return rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     System.err.println("error in colcount");
     return 0;
  }
 }

  public int getRowCount() {
  int totalRows = 0;
  try {
    rs.last();
    totalRows = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();
  } catch(Exception ex)  {
        return 0;
  }
    return totalRows ;
  }
}
```

so, I store database data into the arraylist and then I print the table using the arraylist.
Now in the addRow() function I add to that arraylist an empty record (in my mind an empty record is a record composed of all null ("") strings).
Finally using the fireTableStructureChanged() method I expect the table to refresh itself.. but this will never occur and I don't understand why.

I've already checked that the new row is successfully loaded into the arraylist:
I got all the data stored in the table of the Database into the arraylist and the new row is successfully loaded in the arraylist.
so I swear the problem is about that fireTableStructureChanged() method.

Thanks :3

Comment: Maybe you also need to call `fireTableDataChanged`?

Comment: Tried both fireTableDataChanged and fireTableStructureChanged. Nothing happens when the empty record is added to the ArrayList.

Comment: Including `getRowCount` and `getColumnCount` method implementations in the question would be helpful.

Comment: @tsolakp I didn't add them before 'cause I was trying to modify them since I think the problem is the getrowcount(). Btw now it's all up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow) instead of fireTableStructureChanged()

Here's the javadoc for the structure changed ...

> Notifies all listeners that the table's structure has changed. The number of columns in the table, and the names and types of the new columns may be different from the previous state. If the JTable receives this event and its autoCreateColumnsFromModel flag is set it discards any table columns that it had and reallocates default columns in the order they appear in the model. This is the same as calling setModel(TableModel) on the JTable.

So that one will only work if the columns types changed ...

If you are lazy go for this one: fireTableDataChanged()

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
That's quite embarassing..

@tsolakp you helped me a lot!

Since before using ArrayList I was working on ResultSet directly, I forgot to update getrowcount.
So, since the inserting was only "client side" on the arraylist, the rows displayed were only "n" (where n was the number of rows on the database). So I would never displayed my new row since it was not loaded into the database.

That's all :)

Maybe working hard on coding, makes these errors invisible :X